# Django ORM get all many-to-many fields of an instance

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a model `Project`, which has `m2m` relationship with `Category`, `Specialty`, `Competitor`.

I have an `instance` of this model `Project`. I can get all the fields of the model using

### Fields of model

`object._meta.fields`

This gives me the all the fields in the model; I just iterate over these can check if something is updated by the user or not.

I also want to know what `ManyToMany` relations this object has rather than Statically calling all `project.category_set.all()`

I want to know, if there is any way that i can get a list of all these relation and iterate over them and get they values of these?

### AIM

Check if the data in `ManyToMany` relations have updated by the user or not specific to this instance.

### Code

```
def save(self, request, instance):
    project = super(RequestForm, self).save(commit=False)
    project.competitor.all() # Gives the list which is in data base (not new list form the form values.
    project.save()
    project.instance.save_m2m()
    project.competitor.all() # Gives the list which is in data base (With the changing have been made.
```

How to check if the `Competitor` data has been updated.

Comment: Maybe you could use signals here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/).

Comment: Can you please elaborate? 
I need to take decisions upon checking the change.
I can check for all the fields of the model which are updated, but M2M data remains, 
I want to send an email and store a log file with the comment that which fields were changed. For Signals i can user pre-save (but the questions remains how to compare two values) older and newer?

Comment: If I could get the Older values (which i can) and updated form values, then i do not need signals. i can do it in FormInstance.Save() method also.

Comment: You can't get Form values from the Model (even if you could it wouldn't be a good thing) because Forms are on top of models, not vice versa, while the Form knows about involved models, the Model can not know if it's being called from a Form or something else.

This check should be done inside the Form class or (as Jingo suggested) with a signal, which takes the instance as an argument, thus you can compare instance values with DB values.